# Sum big decimals in pyspark and see rhe entire number

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([["gr1", "1663708559.71"], ["gr1", "123958300.14"],["gr2", "2006101145.31"]]), ["group_col", "numb"])
```

And i want to have a new column with the sum of values grouped by group col. But i don't have a readeble output.

```
df.withColumn("sum_gr", f.sum(df["numb"].cast("double"))).over(Window.partitionBy(df["group_col"]))).show(10, False)
```

After i calculate the sum i have to compare that big value with another big value and even if they are equals, i dont get a match.

I have the followig result:
 For gr1: the sum is 1.7876668500001E9
and i have to compare this value with lets say 1787666850000.143.

What is the best approach when working with big float numbers in pyspark? How should i do to have the entire number with all decimals converted into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast the `sum` to `decimal(38,3)`. Please adjust precision and scale accordingly.

Here is an example:

```
df.groupBy('group_Col').agg(F.sum('numb').cast('decimal(38,3)')).show()

#+---------+--------------------------------+
#|group_Col|CAST(sum(numb) AS DECIMAL(38,3))|
#+---------+--------------------------------+
#|      gr2|                  2006101145.310|
#|      gr1|                  1787666859.850|
#+---------+--------------------------------+
```

Please check syntax of `withColumn` statement for `sum_gr` column. It has 2 extra closing brackets ')' in after 'cast'.

Comment: Is there a way to get all decimals available? Without having to set the scale? I want to diplay all decimals available

Comment: @FlorentinaP - If you don't specify scale and precision with decimal then by default it will take DECIMAL(10,0). So you have to specify. On safer side you can take scale to bigger number eg. 10 or 12. This won't harm.

Comment: Then another question.. how can i remove the zeros ? And have a string containing the final value.